# Macro definition not replaced as expected?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, undef

I followed the online tutorial and wanted to use `#undef` to design my debug output function. I wrote a `debugOut.h` file.
The content is as follows：

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NOOP //(void(0))

#undef DEBUG_PRINT

#if DEBUG_OUT
#define DEBUG_PRINT printf
#else 
#define DEBUG_PRINT(...) NOOP
#endif 

#undef DEBUG_OUT
```

Then I wrote a main function to test whether my design is correct.

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Header/debug_out.h"
#define DEBUG_OUT
int main(){
    DEBUG_PRINT("module1 debug...\n");
    printf("hello,world");
}
```

But the output result is only `hello, world`. Why I defined `#define DEBUG_OUT`, why is `DEBUG_PRINT` not replaced with `printf`

I wrote it based on an online tutorial. I want to write an output function for c++ based on this. But in the sentence `#define DEBUG_PRINT(...) NOOP`, what does `(...)` represent? Is there any way I can output what the macro definition is replaced with?

Comment: Does you compiler accept the `-E`commandline switch?

Comment: At the time the header is read, `DEBUG_OUT` is not defined.  Therefore you get the NOOP version of `DEBUG_PRINT`.  If you want the non-debug version, make sure `DEBUG_OUT` is defined before including the header.

Comment: The `(...)` means it is a variadic macro - one that can accept any number of arguments.  Since it doesn't do anything with the arguments, that macro definition effectively discards all its arguments.   The version of that macro that expands to a call of `printf()` could have also been specified as `#define DEBUG_PRINT(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)` which expands to a call of `printf()` that explicitly passes all arguments (no matter how many) of the macro as arguments to `printf()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The preprocessor basically scans the input from top to bottom. So it first processes the `#if DEBUG_OUT` included from `#include "Header/debug_out.h"` and only *then* it processes `#define DEBUG_OUT`.

You need to make sure `DEBUG_OUT` is defined before the contents of `Header/debug_out.h` are processed. The following should work:

```
#include<iostream>
#define DEBUG_OUT             // first define DEBUG_OUT 
#include "Header/debug_out.h" // when this is processed DEBUG_OUT is defined
int main(){
    DEBUG_PRINT("module1 debug...\n");
    printf("hello,world");
}
```

---

In Addition there is a typo in "Header/debug_out.h":

```
#if DEBUG_OUT
```

should be

```
#ifdef DEBUG_OUT
```

Comment: Oh, I think what you said makes sense. But after I changed it like this, the compilation went wrong. Header/debug_out.h:19:14: error: #if with no expression. But there is a statement after if. Before the change, it can be compiled normally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know what the (...) in #define DEBUG_PRINT(...) NOOP means?

Comment: I avoid macros as far as possible :) But I think it's a variadic macro.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NOOP //(void(0))

#undef DEBUG_PRINT

#if DEBUG_OUT      ///////////should be #ifdef
#define DEBUG_PRINT printf
#else 
#define DEBUG_PRINT(...) NOOP
#endif 

#undef DEBUG_OUT
```

below is copied from the voted most.

```
#include<iostream>
#define DEBUG_OUT             // first define DEBUG_OUT 
#include "Header/debug_out.h" // when this is processed DEBUG_OUT is defined
int main(){
    DEBUG_PRINT("module1 debug...\n");
    printf("hello,world");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know what the (...) in #define DEBUG_PRINT(...) NOOP means?

Comment: #define DEBUG_PRINT(...) NOOP  will co-work with #define NOOP
the result is the DEBUG_PRINT("module1 debug...\n"); will become empty statement.
                   "..." means variadic arguments in C language